# Set part of JTable cells uneditable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, cells

I created JTable in eclipse using "Design" option and now I want to make some cells uneditable. This is my code:

```
    public Frame(int choice) {
       initComponents();
       defaultModel = (DefaultTableModel) m0.getModel();
       if (choice == 0) {
        defaultModel.setColumnCount(7);
        defaultModel.removeRow(6);
       }
    defaultModel.isCellEditable(2,2);
    defaultModel.isCellEditable(3,3);

}
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
    return false;
}
```

Cells (2,2) and (3,3) should be uneditable. But it does not work. Can somebody help?

Comment: have to use proper definition in classes and methods created or defined for this purposes, everything is described in Oracle tutorial [How To use Tables - Creating a Table Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)

Answer (score 1):

Do you see the problem here?:

```
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
    return false;  // !!!!!!!
}
```

> Cells (2,2) and (3,3) should be editable. But it does not work. Can somebody help?

You're setting the cells as ineditable with your isCellEditable(...) method override and then you're inexplicably wondering why they're not editable. Sorry but that's a bit crazy. The solution is to change what is returned by the `isCellEditable(...)` method so that it does what you want it to. If you want it editable for 2,2 and 3,3, then put that logic in the method above.

---

**Edit**
I see that you've edited your question so that now it is:

```
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
    return false;
}
```

> Cells (2,2) and (3,3) should be uneditable. But it does not work. Can somebody help?

That of course changes everything. My guess is that your isCellEditable is not a true override of the JTable or its model. Have you tried adding an @Override annotation before it? Can you show us how it is in fact overriding the current JTable or its model? You need to show that this method is in class that extends JTable or its model and that this is in fact the class that is being used.

Comment: @user2405924: this is getting worse all the time... Please see edit. Your question must show more.